# could not connect to development server-react native ios

Tags: api, react-native, authentication, backend

The project i tried is to authenticate using Post method API services.When i try to run the project, i get the could not connect to development server.

I tried to close the packager and run the react-native start command and opened another tab and run the project using react-native run-ios, build fails saying port already in use.

```
import { AppRegistry, StyleSheet, TextInput, View, Alert, Button, Text } from 'react-native';

class MainProject extends Component {

constructor(props) {

    super(props)

    this.state = {

      UserName: '',
      UserEmail: '',
      UserPassword: ''

    }

  }
  UserRegistrationFunction = () =>{
 const { UserName }  = this.state ;
 const { UserEmail }  = this.state ;
 const { UserPassword }  = this.state ;
fetch('https://reactnativecode.000webhostapp.com/user_registration.php', {
  method: 'POST',
  headers: {
    'Accept': 'application/json',
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
  },
  body: JSON.stringify({
    name: UserName,
    email: UserEmail,
    password: UserPassword
  })
}).then((response) => response.json())
      .then((responseJson) => {

// Showing response message coming from server after inserting records.
        Alert.alert(responseJson);

      }).catch((error) => {
        console.error(error);
      });


  }

  render() {
    return (

<View style={styles.MainContainer}>

        <Text style= {{ fontSize: 20, color: "#000", textAlign: 'center', marginBottom: 15 }}>User Registration Form</Text>

        <TextInput

          // Adding hint in Text Input using Place holder.
          placeholder="Enter User Name"

          onChangeText={UserName => this.setState({UserName})}

          // Making the Under line Transparent.
          underlineColorAndroid='transparent'

          style={styles.TextInputStyleClass}
        />

        <TextInput

          // Adding hint in Text Input using Place holder.
          placeholder="Enter User Email"

          onChangeText={UserEmail => this.setState({UserEmail})}

          // Making the Under line Transparent.
          underlineColorAndroid='transparent'

          style={styles.TextInputStyleClass}
        />

        <TextInput

          // Adding hint in Text Input using Place holder.
          placeholder="Enter User Password"

          onChangeText={UserPassword => this.setState({UserPassword})}

          // Making the Under line Transparent.
          underlineColorAndroid='transparent'

          style={styles.TextInputStyleClass}

          secureTextEntry={true}
        />

        <Button title="Click Here To Register" onPress={this.UserRegistrationFunction} color="#2196F3" />



</View>

    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({

MainContainer :{

justifyContent: 'center',
flex:1,
margin: 10
},

TextInputStyleClass: {

textAlign: 'center',
marginBottom: 7,
height: 40,
borderWidth: 1,
// Set border Hex Color Code Here.
 borderColor: '#2196F3',

 // Set border Radius.
 borderRadius: 5 ,

// Set border Radius.
 //borderRadius: 10 ,
}

});

export default MainProject;
```

Expected result: To see the login screen for user authentication
Actual result: Could not connect to development server

Answer (score 0):

first fire command, `killall node -9` and then fire command `react-native run-ios`.

or

run `rm -rf ios/build/; kill $(lsof -t -i:8081); react-native run-ios`

Comment: i tried this command and i got the error "no bundle url present"

Comment: can you please share the screenshot here?

Comment: No bundle URL present.

Make sure you're running a packager server or have included a .jsbundle file in your application bundle.

RCTFatal
__28-[RCTCxxBridge handleError:]_block_invoke
_dispatch_call_block_and_release
_dispatch_client_callout
_dispatch_main_queue_callback_4CF
__CFRUNLOOP_IS_SERVICING_THE_MAIN_DISPATCH_QUEUE__
__CFRunLoopRun
CFRunLoopRunSpecific
GSEventRunModal
UIApplicationMain
main
start
0x0

Comment: hi, Please check your code, you may have some syntex error.

Comment: syntax error will show error in the line number right?

Comment: yes, that why i asking for screenshot? please share if you don't have any problem

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/196820/discussion-between-saranya-and-vijay-kahar).